# What is the proof of $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a} \left(1+f(x)\right)^{g(x)} = e^{\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a} f(x) \cdot g(x)}$?

Tags: calculus

Since I already learned that formula somewhere, I wanna proof it by myself but im not sure.

What is the proof of $\lim\limits_{x\to a} (1+f(x))^{g(x)} = e^{\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)\cdot g(x)}$
when $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x) = 0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to a} g(x) = \infty$.

Comment: Hint: Let $y=\left(1+f(x)\right)^{g(x)}$. Then $\ln y=g(x) \ln (1+f(x))$. Not try to find $$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{\ln (1+f(x))}{1/g(x)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

This is true only if $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=0$.
$$L=\lim_{x \to a} (1+f(x))^{g(x)}= \lim_{x\to a} \exp[\ln(1+f(x))^{g(x)}]=\exp[\lim_{x\to a}g(x)(\ln(1+f(x))]$$
Next, if only $f(x)$ is small $\ln[1+f(x)]\approx f(x)$
$$L=\exp[\lim_{x\to a} g(x) f(x)]$$

Comment: could you please explain why is ln[1 + f(x)] ≈ f(x) when f(x) is small?

Comment: @Vrdi Ulrich  because $\ln(1+\epsilon)=\epsilon-\epsilon^2/2+...$